# How to use indexOf on a List containing HashMap with multiple key/value pairs

Tags: java, list, comparator, comparable

I have a `List` containing `HashMaps`. Each `HashMap` in the list might have multiple `key/value` pairs. I want to `indexOf` on the list to find out the index of the element where the passed in HashMap is. However, the problem is that e[quals method of HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) looks at all the entire `entrySet` while comparing. Which is not what I want.

Example:

```
    List<HashMap> benefit = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    HashMap map1 = new HashMap();
    map1.put("number", "1");
    benefit.add(map1);
    HashMap map2 = new HashMap();
    map2.put("number", "2");
    map2.put("somethingelse", "blahblah"); //1
    benefit.add(map2);

    HashMap find = new HashMap();
    find.put("number", "2");
    int index = benefit.indexOf(find);
    if (index >= 0)
        System.out.println(benefit.get(index).get("number"));
```

The above code does not print anything because of line with `//1`.

- What do I have to do so that the above code actually prints `2`?
- Is there a way to implement comparable on the list so that I can define
  my own?

Comment: Mike, i'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but there might be a little design flow. Maybe other data structures will simplify your code and make it more efficient. What's your goal? What are you storing?

Comment: So if a passed-in HashMap has the same pairs? Or will `find` always only be one pair and you want to see what index contains that pair?

Comment: @Gevorg you are right. It is a design flaw. It would be nice if I had objects of my class stored in the list rather than hashmaps. Then I could roll out my own `equals()` method. However, there is a lot of legacy code so I would prefer a solution that works on `HashMaps` for the time being.

Comment: @paranoid-android the hashes inside the list can have many key/value pairs but I'll pass in `find` with just one key/value pair. key of `find` will always be same.

Comment: If you want a map of a single element, and don't mind if it's not a HashMap, you can use Collections.singletonMap(key, value). It'll save you a line of code or two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for `retainAll()`, so you can compare only the elements you're interested in:

```
int index = myIndexOf(benefit, find);

...

static int myIndexOf(List<HashMap> benefit, Map find) {
    int i = 0;
    for (Map map : benefit) {
        Map tmp = new HashMap(map);
        tmp.keySet().retainAll(find.keySet());
        if (tmp.equals(find)) {
            return i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It's possible, of course, to declare your own subclass of List that overrides the indexOf method with this behaviour. However, I don't think that's a good idea. It would violate the contract of the indexOf method:

> *returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))*

This would be confusing to someone else maintaining the code. You might then think that you could subclass HashMap to redefine equals, but that would violate the symmetry property of Object.equals().

Comment: one of the lesser known things in Collections. Thanks for sharing. +1

Answer (score 1):

The way you are trying to achieve your goal is wrong. The `indexOf` method works exactly as it should in this case. It is trying to find an exact match, not a partial one.

What you are trying to do, if I get it correctly, is to find a map in your list of maps that contains a specific entry. In this case, you should manually perform this search, by going through all the maps, calling `containsKey ()`, and then comparing the value you are expecting to find with the value associated with the key.

The other way would be to create a proxy class around your `List`, and add a new method `findMapWithEntry (String key, String value)`, which would perform this seach for you (the same search I described above).

Answer (score 0):

You can always override the indexOf method. Looking at the source for ArrayList:

```
   public int indexOf(Object o) {
     if (o == null) {
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         if (elementData[i]==null)
          return i;
     else {
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
           return i;
     }
     return -1;
   }
```

So it's not a very complex search algorithm at all. You may look at something like:

```
List benefit = new ArrayList(){
 public int indexOf(Object o){
      if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         if (elementData[i]==null)
           return i;
      else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) //traverse the hashmaps
         Object key = ((HashMap)o).keySet().get(0); //assuming one pair
         Object val = ((HashMap)o).valueSet().get(0);
         if (
            ((HashMap)elementData[i]).containsKey(key) &&             
            ((HashMap)elementData[i]).get(key).equals(val))
              return i;
      }
      return -1;
 };
```

My advice would be to consider a different data structure, perhaps writing your own one for it.

Comment: But it would break `indexOf`'s contract, as correctly pointed by martielle.

Comment: Yes it would, but the use of the `indexOf` is not conventional here, and can be assumed that it won't be used outside of the requirement. Which is why it would be beneficial to create a new class, perhaps extending ArrayList which would have a redefined `indexOf`.

Comment: If it's not conventional, then maybe creating a new method that would perform the expected contract is a better way. I don't think changing a method's contract is a good thing, and Josh Bloch mentions that exact point in his _Effective Java_ book.

Comment: +1, can't believe creating a new method wasn't the first thing on my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Why not change the way you search?

```
List<Map> matchingBenefits = new ArrayList<Map>();
for (Map m : benefit) {
    if (m.containsKey("number") && m.get("number").equals("2"))
        matchingBenefits.add(m);
}
for (Map m : matchingBenefits) {
    System.out.println(m.get("number"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you cannot change the design, would writing your own find method help?

The code below should work if I understood what you're trying to do and it runs in O(n)

```
public static String find(List<HashMap<String,String>> listMap, String key, String value) {
    for(int i = 0; i < listMap.size(); i++)
        if(listMap.get(i).get(key).equals(value))
            return value;

    return null;
}
```